# how to add same width on bootstrap dropdown menu item as parent item

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

how to add same width on bootstrap dropdown menu item as parent item?

I have 
[image: this menu]

the html is

```
<header class="navbar navbar-purple navbar-static-top bs-docs-nav" role="banner">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://pos.shalvasoft.tk/"><span class="first">ShalvaSoft</span> <span class="second">POS</span></a>
        </div>
        <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown langs">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                        <span id="selectedlang"> ქართული  <i class='flag-icon flag-icon-ge'></i></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li class="hidden"><a href="#" class="lang" data-link="ge">ქართული <i class='flag-icon flag-icon-ge'></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="lang" data-link="ru">русский <i class='flag-icon flag-icon-ru'></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="lang" data-link="en">English <i class='flag-icon flag-icon-us'></i></a></li>    
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

and in css I tryed this code

```
.navbar-purple .dropdown-menu { background-color: rgba(155, 89, 182,0.8); min-width:118px;padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0;}
.navbar-purple .dropdown-menu > li > a { color: #FFFFFF; text-align: right !important; padding: 3px 5px 3px 0;}
```

but nothing happened becouse when the text of parent drop down is in Georgian the text size is larger than in English or in Russian
so I tryed use jquery to check the size of the parent dropdown

```
var langwidth = $('.langs > a').width();
    if(langwidth > 70) {
        $('.navbar-purple .tmenu .dropdown-menu>li>a').css({
            'padding-left': (100 - langwidth + 2) + 'px',
            'padding-right': (100 - langwidth + 2) + 'px'
        });
    }
```

I cannot use if else statement every time becouse this bar is dinamicaly and may be in the future I need to add new item
so the size will not be as I need

please help me

this is jsfiddle link

```
https://jsfiddle.net/giasoft/f0zsroaj/
```

and this is the page where is only this menu and 1 form only so you can change languages and check how it is displaying the drop down content.

```
http://pos.shalvasoft.tk/login/en
```

Thank you for future help.

Comment: apply width of parent tag to child tag.

Comment: and how I can apply the parent tag width?
please show me in the fiddle

Comment: add style="width:130px;" to each <li>

Comment: your fiddle is not working well. please recheck your fiddle. i have used http://pos.shalvasoft.tk/login/en

Comment: I add this ruler
.navbar-purple .dropdown-menu > li{width:130px;}
it is working well in Georgian but now I have problem on Russian and English.

Comment: P.S. please use pos.shalvasoft.tk/login becouse on this page you can change languages and look how the menu is opening.

Comment: please check my answer. i have applied width to 130px to <li>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update toggle menu li tags with this html.

```
<li style="width:130px;" class="dropdown langs open">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="caret"></span>
        <span id="selectedlang"> English  <i class="flag-icon flag-icon-us"></i></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li style="width:130px;"><a href="#" class="lang" data-link="ge">ქართული <i class="flag-icon flag-icon-ge"></i></a></li>
        <li style="width:130px;"><a href="#" class="lang" data-link="ru">русский <i class="flag-icon flag-icon-ru"></i></a></li>
        <li class="hidden"><a href="#" class="lang" data-link="en">English <i class="flag-icon flag-icon-us"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: now everithing is working well. but can I use this rulles in css? I do not need that the style rulles be in the html

Answer (score 8):

I would have actually just set the `ul.dropdown-menu` tag to have a `width` of `100%`, which would ensure it has the same width as its parent `li.dropdown.langs` tag. This, as the accepted answer also illustrated, would be better put into a style tag or external sheet than an inline style.

```
<li class="dropdown langs">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="caret"></span>
        <span id="selectedlang"> English  <i class="flag-icon flag-icon-us"></i></span>
    </a>
    <ul style="width:100%;" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#" class="lang" data-link="ge">ქართული <i class="flag-icon flag-icon-ge"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li style="width:130px;"><a href="#" class="lang" data-link="ru">русский <i class="flag-icon flag-icon-ru"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li class="hidden"><a href="#" class="lang" data-link="en">English <i class="flag-icon flag-icon-us"></i></a>
        </li> 
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply make both the dropdown menu and the parent "dropdown toggle" to take 100% width. here is the CSS rule

```
.dropdown-toggle, 
.dropdown-menu {
    width: 100%;
}
```